# collection view cell Hight and width in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uicollectionview

collection view had multiple images working fine. it's showing like this

[image]

But i want show like this way

[image]

this is code of collection view cell

```
 let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
 layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 0, bottom: 20, right: 0)
 let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
 layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: width/2 , height: width/2 )
 layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
 layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
 collectionView!.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just implement some `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` methods to get the correct size and spacing of the `UICollectionViewCells`.

**Example:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
{
    let cellSize = CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.width - (3 * 10))/2, height: 120)
    return cellSize
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
{
    return 10
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    let sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10)
    return sectionInset
}
```

Just change the size and spacing values according to your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Add this method on your viewcontroller

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: ((self.view.frame.size.width/2) - 10), height: 255)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
collectionViewCellImageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set minimum spacing for cell & line for collection view and implement the bellow delegate

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (collectionView.frame.width/2) - 5, height: collectionView.frame.width/2)
    }
```